# Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured

Tags: logstash

when using logstash I see an error like this one :

```
[2019-03-14T12:59:39,516][WARN ][logstash.codecs.plain    ] 
Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured.
{
:text=>"08/02/2019 22:45:06 ||  : Service Reglement, ValiderReglementBilling:Echec de validation de r\\xE9glement dans NaviBilling. Transaction N\\xB0: 20194160773This message is for C/AL programmers: The call to member CreationFacture failed: Input string was not in a correct format..\\r", 
:expected_charset=>"UTF-8"
}
```

I do not know what codec should be used for the correct format of events ?? The problem is in the subject field.

my logstash.conf is :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:\ELK\log\WCF-08-02-2019-7e8b53db-Error.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
  filter {
    grok {
      match => {
        "message" => ["%{DATESTAMP:time} \|\|  :%{DATA:Name_Service}:%{DATA:Action}: %{GREEDYDATA:Gravity}",
          "%{DATESTAMP:time} \|\|  :%{DATA:Name_Service},%{DATA:Action}: %{GREEDYDATA:Gravity}",
          "%{DATESTAMP:time} \|\|  :%{DATA:Name_Service}, %{DATA:Action}: %{GREEDYDATA:Gravity}"
        ]
      }
    }
  }

  output {
    elasticsearch {
      action => "index"
      hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
      index => "logstash-pfe2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
```